# Reset input value button only visible on focused input not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

The task seems quite simple, so I'm hoping to find a simple solution, possibly plain CSS.

I have an input field. If selected, a button with some click event shall appear. As I want to keep it simple, I'm using CSS to hide the button if input is not focused.

But the the click is never executed. It seems CSS is applied before the click, so when the onclick is triggered, the button is already gone.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index].value = "";
  };
});
```

```css
.hide>input:not(:focus)+button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="working">
      <button>Reset</button>
    </div>

    <div class="hide">
      <input type="text" value="not working">
      <button>Reset</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using JS so try this , ```$(':text').focus(function(e){
    $('.list_search').toggle();
}).blur(function(e){
    $('.list_search').toggle();
});```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index].value = "";
  };
});
```

```css
.hide>input:not(:focus)+button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="working">
      <button>Reset</button>
    </div>

    <div class="hide">
      <input type="text" value="not working">
      <button onmousedown="return false">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I found it myself, it's as simply as I expected:

```
<button onmousedown="return false">Reset</button>
```

does the trick.

Comment: It's actually, better than my solution, because the focus stays on the input. You should even add it to the other button.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like your right about your supposition. It really does look like CSS is applied before the javascript.

You can solve it by adding a transition delay on the css property.
Doesn't work with `display` so I had to use `visibility` instead. You can add `position: absolute;` if you want it to behave like `display: none`.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[index].value = "";
  };
});
```

```css
button {
  transition: visibility 0.05s;
}

.hide>input:not(:focus)+button {
  visibility: hidden;
  /*position: absolute; Uncomment to obtain the same effect as display: none*/
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="working">
    <button>Reset</button>
  </div>

  <div class="hide">
    <input type="text" value="not working">
    <button>Reset</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```